# Mounting a host directory through docker-compose file version "3" and re-using the data-volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have Docker commands to create a container and then use that container's name with ***--volumes-from*** to run another container and it works fine -

```
docker create -v /home/dev/docker/my/config:/home/myuser/4.0/config --name shared-config my/configurator:4.0.0
```

The above would create a new container by name **shared-config** from image **my/configurator:4.0.0**

and when trying to run any other container (say my/oms:4.0.0) I can simply use volume from container named shared-config using ***--volumes-from***

```
docker run --volumes-from shared-config -p 8083:8080 -d my/oms:4.0.0
```

using ***--volumes-from*** we can use the volume multiple times in which ever container it is required.

Till here everything seems fine.

Now, I am trying to do the above in docker-compose using file-format version "3" and not able to understand **how will I be able to re-use data-volume once it is created**. Since as per docker-compose in version 3  they have [discontinued use of ***--volumes-from***](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-3).
They say -

> To share a volume between services, define it using the top-level volumes option and reference it from each service that shares it using the service-level volumes option.

In above statement they are referring to named volumes, please refer from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volume-configuration-reference).

But I just want to mount a host directory as a data volume and re-use that data volume. My question is how do I reuse this data-volume through docker-compose file version "3".
To the simplest, for each service I want to run through docker-compose I can use volume key at service level

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-oms:
    image: my/oms:4.0.0
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/dev/docker/my/config:/home/myuser/4.0/config
```

But what if I want to use my host's directory (/home/dev/docker/my/config) as a data volume in different services. Should I have the volume key for each service or actually there is a better way in docker-compose version "3" where I can re-use the data-volume in other services (how we did using --volumes-from).

Any pointers or suggestions or something that I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option to avoid repeating syntax is to extend your docker-compose.yml using the [extends option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services):

So you can have a common-services.yml that looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  generic-vol:
    volumes:
      - /home/dev/docker/my/config:/home/myuser/4.0/config
```

And then your docker-compose.yml gets updated to look like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-oms:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: generic-vol
    image: my/oms:4.0.0
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
```

Note that `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml` may not support all these options, I've encountered issues using variables and multiple docker-compose files for my project. The solution to that is to use docker-compose to parse the file into something the stack deploy can use with `docker-compose config >docker-compose.stack.yml` and then pass that yml file to your stack deploy.

A second option is to utilize the features of the yml syntax itself. It allows anchors and references to those anchors. That syntax looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-oms:
    image: my/oms:4.0.0
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
    volumes: &common-vol
      - /home/dev/docker/my/config:/home/myuser/4.0/config
  my-xyz:
    image: my/xyz:4.0.0
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    volumes: *common-vol
```

The first `&common-vol` creates an anchor, and the later `*common-vol` is a reference to that same part of yml data.

Comment: second option you suggested works for me. Thank you.